# sublime text3 is not displaying utf8 character but their codes

Tags: python, json, unicode, utf-8, sublimetext3

I'm dealing with some german text data. I tried to save some metadata into a JSON file in python.

Here is how the metadata looks like(as you could notice, there are ä, ö characters):

```
{'pages': ['kitchwitch.ch_posts.csv',
  'Sujetbaizinbasel_posts.csv',
  'Guggenmusik-Moore-Schränzer-149777592206118_posts.csv',
  'zueundrichproductions_posts.csv',
  'glueckshof_posts.csv',
  'Lieberockt_posts.csv',
  'Pfadi-Schöftle-699078857125683_posts.csv'...
```

```
with open('./gsw_fb_r1_metadata.json','w',encoding='utf8' )as f:
    json.dump(metadata,f)
```

But when I open it with Sublime Text3, I get the following:

```
{"pages": ["kitchwitch.ch_posts.csv", "Sujetbaizinbasel_posts.csv", 
"Guggenmusik-Moore-Schra\u0308nzer-149777592206118_posts.csv", 
"zueundrichproductions_posts.csv", "glueckshof_posts.csv", 
"Lieberockt_posts.csv", "Pfadi-Sch\u00f6ftle-699078857125683_posts.csv",
```

So the ö and ä are not displayed properly. How could I get them displayed normally as in Python? Is this problem linked to Sublime Text or to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is valid JSON.  The default is to write the data using only ASCII and Unicode escape codes.  When you load the JSON back into Python with `json.load()` the strings will contain the original characters again.

If you want the JSON text file to be readable instead of using escape codes, you can use `ensure_ascii=False`:

```
with open('./gsw_fb_r1_metadata.json','w',encoding='utf8' )as f:
    json.dump(metadata,f,ensure_ascii=False)
```

This will write the data as UTF-8 to the file and be readable in a UTF-8-capable text editor.